# Does Google Actions Support Websockets?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, vui

I am trying to build a Rocket Chat Google Action and one of the major advantage of RC is it's [Realtime API's](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/) however they require Websocket to get access. I know that Dialogflow can be used for Websocket's but does Google Actions support it?

I am using Dialogflow along with Firebase as backend for my Action.

Comment: Maybe you can describe an architectural data flow.  Websockets is a technology for streaming data bi-directionally from a browser to a server.  What kind of data are you thinking would be streamed and in which directions?

Comment: Data would be text messages in both directions, we are looking at a pub-sub talk if you want more details please visit here => https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/realtime-api/. Basically I want an open connection to "server push" of ANY INCOMING messages and/or state changes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Actions on Google is the technology to allow you to write custom processing for the Google Assistant product.  If you have a front-end that is not Google Assistant then I'm not seeing how Actions on Google plays into the story.   If you wish to respond to user originated questions through your own custom logic, then Dialogflow seems like the way to go.  My gut is telling me that Google doesn't provide an API to allow the services called by Google Assistant to be called by anything but Google Assistant or licensed providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions on Google is a platform for stateless applications running through a REST API call. In this model, the user sends one request to your server and they get back one response.

Actions on Google itself doesn't support web sockets, but you are able to define a cloud function like Firebase to do advanced fulfillment. While you may be able to get web sockets to work in your function, you'd still need to adjust the Action's conversational flow to work in a request/response fashion instead of listening to web sockets continually.